# Comparing 2 Csv files having 12 million record in each file by sorting them first gives Out Of Memory Exception

Tags: c#, .net, linq, out-of-memory

I am trying to compare two Csv files that has 12 million records in each file, Before comparing files I want to sort them in ascending order and then compare them. I have tried below code but it gives Out Of Memory Exception.

```
        public void SortCsv(string originalPath1, string originalPath2)
        {
            var lines1 = File.ReadLines(originalPath1, Encoding.Default);
            var sorted1 = lines1.Skip(1).OrderBy(row => row).Select(row => row).ToList();
            
            var lines2 = File.ReadLines(originalPath2, Encoding.Default);
            var sorted2 = lines2.Skip(1).OrderBy(row => row).Select(row => row).ToList();

            var extraFiles1Csv = sorted1.Except(sorted2, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
            var extraFiles2Csv = sorted2.Except(sorted1, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

            if(extraFiles1Csv.Count() > 0)
            foreach (var item in extraFiles1Csv)
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            if (extraFiles1Csv.Count() > 0)
            foreach (var item in extraFiles2Csv)
                Console.WriteLine(item);

            Console.WriteLine("Record is matched");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

I am expecting the that it should sort the data of both csv file and compare them and if there is any mismatch then it should return mismatch record else it should print files matched.

Answer (score 0):

By having linesX and sortedX like that you are keeping each file in memory 2ce
and i think you can drop the select

combining it would halve the memory usage

```
var lines1 = File.ReadLines(originalPath1, Encoding.Default).Skip(1).OrderBy(row => row).ToList();
```

further i would have a look at some csv nuget package like Sylvan.Data.Csv
to read your files, these typically have better speed and memory handeling than trying to do it yourself. (and object mapping 2 ;) )